# Setting reverse PTR

Tags: server, cpanel, ip-address

I have a cPanel server at Hosting Fever with following IPs:
`103.242.119.56` (main server IP) and `103.242.119.71`.

I have several sites on main IP while one site on dedicated IP `103.242.119.71`. Mails from `hostingfever.in` and may be other goes to spam/junk.

Now I want to setup reverse PTR record for my cPanel mails not marked as spam as stated by mxstuff and `intodns.com`.

But not sure how to do and which IP to use and where? Can anyone check my domain and guide me?

Answer (score 4):

PTR records can be set by your service provider. If the IP is delegated into their ownership, they are the ones who can set the PTR record.